# Antiderivative $f(x)=\int_{a}^{x} g(x)$ is differentiable almost everywhere on (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

An exercise in Royden & Fitzpatrick asks to show that if g is integrable on [a,b] and we define the antiderivative of g as:
$f(x)=\int_{a}^{x} g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then f is differentiable almost everywhere on (a,b).

Of course, we want to use the Lebesgue Theorem: $f$ monotone on $(a,b)=>f$ diff a.e. on $(a,b)$. But I'm having trouble with the logic of showing monotonicity. I want for any $x>y$ in $(a,b)$, $f(x)>f(y)$ or $f(x)<f(y)$,for either increasing or decreasing. I have:

$\int_{a}^{x} g(x)-\int_{a}^{y} g(x)=\int_{y}^{x}g(x)$. Now, if g(x)=0, then $\int_{y}^{x}g(x)=0$. Otherwise we have inequality in either direction and we still get monotonicity. Is this correct?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that $f$ is not monotone in general, if $g(x)$ oscillate between postive and negative values.

Comment: No, you would need $g$ positive (or negative) on an interval.  What if, on every interval, there are points where $g$ is positive and other points where $g$ is negative?  Your original $f$ need not be monotone... but perhaps you can get around that...

Comment: @GEdgar, I'm starting to think that I just don't have monotonicity, and this question is meant as a demonstration that the lebesgue theorem does not work in the converse direction, even though I can show this is differentiable, it is not monotone.

Comment: If you had two functions, both differentiable almost everywhere, their _difference_ would also be differentiable almost everywhere I think...

Comment: @GEdgar: If I write $g=g_1-g_2$ for $g_1$ and $g_2$ nonnegative functions, I can break apart the integral in f(x) into the difference of two integrals with nonnegative integrands, so they are both increasing: $\int_{a}^{x}g_1(x) - \int_{a}^{x}g_2(x)$. But how can I claim that this difference is monotone as well?

Comment: Actually, as @DavidC.Ullrich points out, if I can show that the difference of a.e. differentiable functions is differentiable a.e. then I'll be done. 


Am I justified in saying that if $f=f_1 - f_2$, the difference of two a.e. differentiable functions, then set of all points where $f$ is not differentiable is the union of points where $f_1$ is not differentiable and $f_2$ is not differentiable, which is the union of two sets of measure zero, thus measure zero itself?